# Generalized Eigenvector Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am reviewing a paper in which the solution to 
$$x =\max_\bf{v}\frac{\alpha \bf{v}^\dagger \bf{h}\bf{h}^\dagger \bf{v}}{\beta+\gamma\bf{v}^\dagger \bf{D} \bf{v}},\;\mathrm{such\;that\;\bf{v}^\dagger(\gamma\bf{I}+\alpha \hat{\bf{D}})\bf{v} <\delta}$$
is said to be
$$x= \alpha \bf{h}^\dagger\left(\frac{\beta(\gamma \bf{I}+\alpha\hat{\bf{D}})}{\delta}+ \gamma{\bf{D}}\right)^{-1} \bf{h}, $$
where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ are positive scalars, $\bf{I}$ is an appropriately dimensioned identity matrix, $\bf v$ and $\bf h$ are complex column vectors and $\bf{D},\hat{\bf{D}}$  are real diagonal matrices.

It is claimed that the problem is a generalized eigenvector problem. I've been scouring the internet for a similar example that I can correlate with this one, but haven't had any luck. Could anyone explain how this solution is obtained?

Comment: I feel like you should define what all these things are, not sure if I can help, but I'm currently stuck with thinking that you want $x$ to be real, so $v$ and $h$ are probably vectors in $\mathbb C^n$? Also, what is $\hat{\bf D}$?

Comment: @Dom Sorry, yes. The edit has been made

Comment: Is there some relationship between $\bf D$ and $\hat{\bf D}$? The notation suggests there might be but I can't recall this notation (other than from quantum mechanics where it is used to just denote linear operators).

Comment: @Dom Sorry, nope.

Comment: I think that the conditions are $D\geq  0,\hat{\bf{D}}\geq 0$ and $v^*(\gamma I+\alpha \hat{\bf{D}}) v =\delta$.

Comment: @loup blanc can you elaborate?

Comment: 1. $D\geq 0$, otherwise $\beta +\gamma v^*DV$ may be $0$. 2. $\hat{\bf{D}}\geq 0$, otherwise $v^*(\gamma I+\alpha \hat{\bf{D}})v <\delta$ does not imply that $v$ is bounded. 3. For the equality, see the case when $n=1$.